# How to parse string for port number in ksh

Tags: text-processing, ksh, docker

I want to parse the port number that I need from the output of the `docker port` command.  The `docker port <container-name>` command returns output as follows:

```
15672/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:49187 5672/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:49188
5678/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:49189
```

So it is either a single port number or 2 port numbers.

Thankfully, in the case that the command spews out 2 port numbers, I always need only the second one displayed. To clarify, in the two examples above, I need to parse out `49188` and `49189` port values from the output of the `docker port` command.

What is the shortest way of achieving this?

Comment: `sed 's/.*://'` or `awk -F: '{print $NF}'` applied to that output would output anything after the last `:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a simple job for `sed`:

```
docker port <container-name> | sed 's/^.*:\([0-9]*\)$/\1/'
```

Or if you prefer `awk`:

```
docker port <container-name> | awk -F':' '{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker port <container-name> | while read -r line;do echo ${line##*:};done
```

Comment: you should avoid those `while read...` constructs: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice/169765#169765

Comment: @ValentinB.: show us the correct with ksh builtins only.

Comment: If you want to do it with built-ins only, your way is the best indeed. But what's wrong with using `sed` or `gawk`? Most if not all `ksh` implementation will have them readily available. Some features of those tools will be implementation-dependant, but for a straightforward case like this, you only need basic features that will be present on all standard implementations.